# What is this Basel-like sum of inverses?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I ran across this sum and thought it looked very familiar but can't place it and had trouble searching for it. Does anyone recognize it or have an idea where I should look? I would like to know its sum.

> $$F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i(n-i)}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1{i(n-i)}=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left[\frac1i+\frac1{n-i}\right]=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1i+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1{n-i}=\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1i=\frac2nH_{n-1}$$
Where $H_k$ denotes the $k^\text{th}$ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Thanks! That was fast.

Comment: @mim Glad to help! Feel free to accept the answer if your question is completely answered.